# How do I send an email when the CloseDate in opportunity is changed?

Tags: workflow

Hey I am working on this project where an email should be sent 5 days before the CloseDate in an opportunity. This is to be done using workflows only. the ISCHANGED function doesn't work with time dependent workflows and I tried doing the 'CloseDate <> NUll' but it still wasn't firing the email. What should be the criteria in the time dependant workflow actions? 5 Days Before Rule Trigger Date or 5 Days Before CloseDate?

Answer (score 0):

Rule criteria should be

Closed date  equals TODAY

and rule should trigger 5 days before closed date.

you can check it in your dev org. it's working fine for me